# Accessing PHP cookie from another php script

Tags: php, cookies

I have a problem accessing a cookie variable from another php script. Here's the code snippet

```
if (isset($remember) && $remember == 'on') {

    setcookie("username", $user, time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30));
    setcookie("password", $pass, time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30));  
}
```

How can I access the cookie content from an external script? Thanks

Comment: **dont pass password around in cookies** VERY UNSAFE. You are just giving away the key to this users kindom!

Comment: Look at the `$_COOKIE` array. All your cookies are passed to all your scripts. assuming they have not timed out

Answer (score 0):

When you send HTTP request from external script, The `setcookie()` method will append a new header to the HTTP response header called `Set-Cookie`.

```
Set-Cookie: username=myUserName
Set-Cookie: password=myUserPass
```

To read those cookies (actually all we need is to parse HTTP header from the response) use something like this:

```
file_get_contents("http://localhost:8080/test.php");

$receivedCookies = array();
$headerCount = count($http_response_header);

for($i = 0; $i < $headerCount; $i++){
    if(strpos($http_response_header[$i], "Set-Cookie") !== false){
        $receivedCookies[] = $http_response_header[$i];
    }
}

var_dump($receivedCookies);
```